# Read json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array

```
     Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Graslei BVBA
            [address] => Belgium  Bent
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Red Poppy SPRL
            [address] => Belgium  4900 Spa
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Loula Bee
            [address] => Belgium  Liege
        )

)
```

I pass array in javascript function as `json_encode`.

Please anybody can help me to read this JSON in javascript.

```
 var info = {
"1":{"title":"Graslei BVBA","address":"Belgium  Bent"},
"2":{"title":"Red Poppy SPRL","address":"Belgium  4900 Spa"},
"3":{"title":"Loula Bee","address":"Belgium  Liege"}
}
```

I want address from above to be read.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: info.1.address? info.2.address?

Comment: What have you tried? Because you can just do something like mainelement.key.wantedelement ...

Comment: doesn't work with numbers only as far as i can tell

Comment: The JSON posted is not an array, it is just an object. A JSON array would be something like `[{'title': 'some title'},{'title': 'another title'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var info = {"1":{"title":"Graslei BVBA","address":"Belgium  Bent"},"2":{"title":"Red Poppy SPRL","address":"Belgium  4900 Spa"},"3":{"title":"Loula Bee","address":"Belgium  Liege"}};

/*
* info[number][string] 
*/

info[1] // Object {title: "Graslei BVBA", address: "Belgium  Bent"}
info[1]["address"] //  "Belgium  Bent" 


// for 
for (var i in info) (function(title, address) {

    console.log(title, address); // print title and address

}(info[i]["title"], info[i]["address"]));
```

see sample; http://jsfiddle.net/DHeUL/

Comment: I have tried all the answers given here. But no success, when I alert(address); it shows undefined.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use the index way of retrieving the value. Something like:

```
var info = {"1":{"title":"Graslei BVBA","address":"Belgium  Bent"},"2":{"title":"Red Poppy SPRL","address":"Belgium  4900 Spa"},"3":{"title":"Loula Bee","address":"Belgium  Liege"}};

$('P').append(info["1"].address);
```

You could even do this:

```
var addr = info["1"]["address"];
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/2sTY6/

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers support JSON.parse(), which is defined in ECMA-262 5th Edition (the specification that JS is based on). Its usage is simple:

```
var json = '{"result":xyz,"count":1}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);

  alert(obj.count);
```

For the browsers that don't you can implement it using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Answer (score 0):

Like the below:

```
info[1].address
info[2].address
```

But you may consider use an array instead of such object.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for(i in info){
    data=info[i];
    console.log("title: "+data.title+"\taddress: "+data.address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var info = {
            "1":{"title":"Graslei BVBA","address":"Belgium  Bent"},
   "2":{"title":"Red Poppy SPRL","address":"Belgium  4900 Spa"},
   "3":{"title":"Loula Bee","address":"Belgium  Liege"}
    }
     
for(var obj in info){ //repeats all the objects of "info"
    console.log("obj: "+obj);//prints "1","2","3" in the console
    for(var key in info[obj]){//repeats all the objects of "info[obj]" 
   console.log("key: "+key);//key is "title","address" of info[obj]
   console.log("value: "+info[obj][key]);//value "Graslei BVBA" for info["1"]["title"] and so on.
      
 }
     
}
```

[output of the given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTzyR.png)